# Using is_tax with multiple taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy

I have multiple taxonomies set-up which are being used in conjunction with a custom post type.

It's all working well and I can view different posts depending on the URL structure, e.g.

/packages/package-type/charter/

/packages/package-type/charter/package-location/indonesia/

/packages/package-type/charter/package-location/indonesia/package-price/high-to-low/

Now, if I want to target one of those taxonomies, I can put in my archive.php file:

```
<?php if(is_tax( 'package-price', 'high-to-low' )) : ?>
  High-to-low Taxonomy
<?php endif; ?>
```

And that works, but **only** if the URL is just /packages/package-price/high-to-low/

It won't work if there are multiple taxonomies, e.g. /packages/package-type/charter/package-price/high-to-low/

Any idea how I can get the is_tax conditional to work if it's viewing multiple taxonomies?

Many thanks!

Comment: how have you achieved this URL structure? You'll probably have to look directly at the query vars within the query object to determine what is being displayed.

Comment: I'm using a plugin called "Beautiful Taxonomy Filters". So if I view the first taxonomy (e.g. /package-type/surf-charter/) it has a drop-down which I can select additional taxonomies to filter.